# Extract Month, Year (Netezza SQL)

Tags: sql, date, netezza

My data type is a date formatted as "YYYY-MON-DD" and I would like to extract the month and year to be formatted as "MON YYYY" while keeping the data type as date so that I will be able to use it with the ADD_MONTHS function. Is there a way to do so? I extract the date from the data field called date_process.

This is what I thought of but it doesnt seem to be working.

SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PROCESS_DATE,'YYYY-MON'), 'MON YYYY') AS PERIOD,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored in an internal format, not as a string.

If you want to see the value in a particular format, then you need to convert it to a string. Hence, drop the final `to_date()`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(PROCESS_DATE, 'MON YYYY') AS PERIOD,
```

Comment: Sorry I missed out some things in my question. I actually need the "MON YYYY" to be a date data type so I could use it with the function ADD_MONTHS